# Toy Robot coding puzzle with Java

Tags: java, api, rest, spring

The following code is my solution to a code challenge I submitted a few days ago. I got rejected straight away with no feedback and I've wondered why.

[Here](https://github.com/AyaAzzam/toy-robot-puzzle) is the full code repo.

> **Requirements**
>
> The application is a simulation of a toy robot moving on a square
>   tabletop, of dimensions 5 x 5 units. There are no other obstructions
>   on the table surface. The robot is free to roam around the surface of
>   the table, but must be prevented from falling to destruction. Any
>   movement that would result in the robot falling from the table must be
>   prevented, however further valid movement commands must still be
>   allowed. Create an application that can read in commands of the
>   following form:
>
> PLACE X,Y,F
>
> MOVE
>
> LEFT
>
> RIGHT
>
> REPORT
>
> PLACE will put the toy robot on the table in position X,Y and facing
>   NORTH, SOUTH, EAST or WEST.
>
> The origin (0,0) can be considered to be the SOUTH WEST most corner.
>
> MOVE will move the toy robot one unit forward in the direction it is
>   currently facing.
>
> LEFT and RIGHT will rotate the robot 90 degrees in the specified
>   direction without changing the position of the robot.
>
> REPORT will announce the X,Y and F of the robot.
>
> Constraints:
>
> - The application must be a Spring-Boot-Application
> - Input must be realised over the REST-API, take care when designing the REST-API
> - The robot that is not on the table can choose the ignore the MOVE, LEFT, RIGHT and REPORT commands.
> - The robot must not fall off the table during movement. This also includes the initial placement of the toy robot.
> - Any move that would cause the robot to fall must be ignored.
> - It is not required to provide any graphical output showing the movement of the toy robot.
>
> Plain input Examples:
>
> PLACE 0,0,NORTH MOVE REPORT
>
> Output: 0,1,NORTH
>
> PLACE 0,0,NORTH LEFT REPORT
>
> Output: 0,0,WEST
>
> PLACE 1,2,EAST MOVE MOVE LEFT MOVE REPORT
>
> Output: 3,3,NORTH
>
> MOVE REPORT
>
> Output: ROBOT MISSING

**Solution**

**ToyRobotApplication.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ToyRobotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToyRobotApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**RobotSimulationController.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.controller;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.SimulationRound;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.service.RobotSimulationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class RobotSimulationController {

    private RobotSimulationService simulationService;

    @Autowired
    public RobotSimulationController(RobotSimulationService simulationService) {
        this.simulationService = simulationService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/robot/simulation")
    public ResponseEntity<Report> newSimulationRound(@RequestBody SimulationRound simulationRound) {
        Report report = simulationService.start(simulationRound);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(report);
    }
}
```

**RobotSimulationService.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.service;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Robot;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.SimulationRound;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command.Command;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command.CommandFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RobotSimulationService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RobotSimulationService.class);

    public Report start(SimulationRound simulationRound) {

        Robot robot = new Robot();

        Report report = new Report();

        for (String commandString : simulationRound.getCommands()) {

            Command command = CommandFactory.getCommand(commandString);

            if (command != null) {

                command.execute(robot, report);

            } else {

                log.debug("Wrong command: " + commandString);
            }
        }

        return report;
    }

}
```

**SimulationRound.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SimulationRound {

    private List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getCommands() {
        return commands;
    }

    public void setCommands(List<String> commands) {
        this.commands = commands;
    }

    public void addCommand(String command) {
        commands.add(command);
    }
}
```

**Robot.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model;

public class Robot {

    public static final Integer MAX_POSITION = 4;
    public static final Integer MIN_POSITION = 0;

    private Integer xPosition;

    private Integer yPosition;

    private CardinalDirection cardinalDirection;

    public Robot() {
    }

    public Robot(Integer xPosition, Integer yPosition, CardinalDirection cardinalDirection) {
        this.xPosition = xPosition;
        this.yPosition = yPosition;
        this.cardinalDirection = cardinalDirection;
    }

    public Integer getXPosition() {
        return xPosition;
    }

    public void setXPosition(Integer xPosition) {
        this.xPosition = xPosition;
    }

    public Integer getYPosition() {
        return yPosition;
    }

    public void setYPosition(Integer yPosition) {
        this.yPosition = yPosition;
    }

    public CardinalDirection getCardinalDirection() {
        return cardinalDirection;
    }

    public void setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection cardinalDirection) {
        this.cardinalDirection = cardinalDirection;
    }

    public boolean isOnTable() {
        return xPosition != null && yPosition != null && cardinalDirection != null;
    }

    public String getCurrentStatus() {
        return String.join(",", xPosition.toString(), yPosition.toString(), cardinalDirection.toString());
    }


    public void increaseYPosition() {
        yPosition++;
    }

    public void decreaseYPosition() {
        yPosition--;
    }

    public void increaseXPosition() {
        xPosition++;
    }

    public void decreaseXPosition() {
        yPosition++;
    }
}
```

**Report.java**
    package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Report {

    private List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(List<String> output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void addOutput(String outupt) {
        this.output.add(outupt);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Report report = (Report) o;
        return Objects.equals(output, report.output);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(output);
    }
}
```

**CardinalDirection.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model;

public enum CardinalDirection {
    EAST, WEST, SOUTH, NORTH
}
```

**Command.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;


import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Robot;

public abstract class Command {

    public abstract void execute(Robot robot, Report report);
}
```

**CommandFactory.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;

public class CommandFactory {

    private static final String PLACE_COMMAND_REGEX = "^(PLACE)\\s\\d+,\\d+,(NORTH|WEST|EAST|SOUTH)$";

    public static Command getCommand(String commandString) {

        if (commandString.matches(PLACE_COMMAND_REGEX)) {
            return new PlaceCommand(commandString);

        } else if (commandString.equals(CommandType.LEFT.name())) {
            return new LeftCommand();

        } else if (commandString.equals(CommandType.RIGHT.name())) {
            return new RightCommand();

        } else if (commandString.equals(CommandType.REPORT.name())) {
            return new ReportCommand();

        } else if (commandString.equals(CommandType.MOVE.name())) {
            return new MoveCommand();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**CommandType,java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;

public enum CommandType {
    PLACE, MOVE, LEFT, RIGHT, REPORT
}
```

**LeftCommand.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.CardinalDirection;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Robot;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LeftCommand extends Command {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LeftCommand.class);

    public void execute(Robot robot, Report report) {

        if (!robot.isOnTable()) {
            log.debug("Left command ignored");
        } else {
            switch (robot.getCardinalDirection()) {
                case NORTH:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.WEST);
                    break;
                case SOUTH:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.EAST);
                    break;
                case EAST:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.NORTH);
                    break;
                case WEST:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.SOUTH);
                    break;
            }
            log.debug("The robot is rotating 90 degree to " + robot.getCardinalDirection());
        }

    }
}
```

**MoveCommand.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Robot;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MoveCommand extends Command {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MoveCommand.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(Robot robot, Report report) {
        if (!robot.isOnTable()) {
            log.debug("Move command ignored");
        } else {
            switch (robot.getCardinalDirection()) {
                case NORTH:
                    if (robot.getYPosition() < Robot.MAX_POSITION) {
                        robot.increaseYPosition();
                        log.debug("The robot is moving");

                    } else {
                        log.debug("Move command ignored");
                    }
                    break;

                case SOUTH:
                    if (robot.getYPosition() > Robot.MIN_POSITION) {
                        robot.decreaseYPosition();
                        log.debug("The robot is moving");
                    } else {
                        log.debug("Move command ignored");
                    }
                    break;

                case EAST:
                    if (robot.getXPosition() < Robot.MAX_POSITION) {
                        robot.increaseXPosition();
                        log.debug("The robot is moving");
                    } else {
                        log.debug("Move command ignored");
                    }
                    break;

                case WEST:
                    if (robot.getXPosition() > Robot.MIN_POSITION) {
                        robot.decreaseXPosition();
                        log.debug("The robot is moving");
                    } else {
                        log.debug("Move command ignored");
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**PlaceCommand.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.CardinalDirection;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Robot;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class PlaceCommand extends Command {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PlaceCommand.class);

    private String commandString;

    PlaceCommand(String commandString) {
        this.commandString = commandString;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Robot robot, Report report) {
        String placementArgs = StringUtils.substringAfter(commandString, CommandType.PLACE.name());
        String[] args = StringUtils.split(placementArgs, ",");

        Integer initialX = Integer.parseInt(args[0].trim());
        Integer initialY = Integer.parseInt(args[1].trim());

        if (initialX <= Robot.MAX_POSITION && initialX >= Robot.MIN_POSITION
                && initialY <= Robot.MAX_POSITION && initialY >= Robot.MIN_POSITION) {
            robot.setXPosition(initialX);
            robot.setYPosition(initialY);
            robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.valueOf(args[2].trim()));
            log.debug("Robot is placed at " + robot.getCurrentStatus());
        } else {
            log.debug("Place command ignored");
        }
    }
}
```

**ReportCommand.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Robot;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ReportCommand extends Command {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportCommand.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(Robot robot, Report report) {
        if (!robot.isOnTable()) {
            log.debug("Missing Robot");
            report.addOutput("ROBOT MISSING");
        } else {
            report.addOutput(robot.getCurrentStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

**RightCommand.java**

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.command;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.CardinalDirection;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Robot;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class RightCommand extends Command {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RightCommand.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(Robot robot, Report report) {
        if (!robot.isOnTable()) {
            log.debug("Right command ignored");
        } else {
            switch (robot.getCardinalDirection()) {
                case NORTH:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.EAST);
                    break;
                case SOUTH:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.WEST);
                    break;
                case EAST:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.SOUTH);
                    break;
                case WEST:
                    robot.setCardinalDirection(CardinalDirection.NORTH);
                    break;
            }
            log.debug("The robot is rotating 90 degree to " + robot.getCardinalDirection());

        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.puzzle</groupId>
    <artifactId>toy-robot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>toy-robot</name>
    <description>Toy Robot coding puzzle</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and Finally a controller test

```
package com.puzzle.toyrobot.controller;

import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.Report;
import com.puzzle.toyrobot.model.SimulationRound;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RobotSimulationControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void simulationReportAsExpectedTest() {

        Report report = new Report();
        report.addOutput("0,1,NORTH");

        SimulationRound round = new SimulationRound();
        round.addCommand("PLACE 0,0,NORTH");
        round.addCommand("LEFT");
        round.addCommand("RIGHT");
        round.addCommand("MOVE");
        round.addCommand("REPORT");

        HttpEntity<Object> simulationRound = getHttpEntity(round);

        ResponseEntity<Report> resultAsset = template.postForEntity("/robot/simulation", simulationRound, Report.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(resultAsset.getBody(), report);
    }

    @Test
    public void missingRobotTest() {

        Report report = new Report();
        report.addOutput("ROBOT MISSING");

        SimulationRound round = new SimulationRound();
        round.addCommand("MOVE");
        round.addCommand("REPORT");

        HttpEntity<Object> simulationRound = getHttpEntity(round);
        ResponseEntity<Report> resultAsset = template.postForEntity("/robot/simulation", simulationRound, Report.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(resultAsset.getBody(), report);
    }


    @Test
    public void ignoringWrongCommandTest() {

        Report report = new Report();
        report.addOutput("0,0,WEST");

        SimulationRound round = new SimulationRound();
        round.addCommand("PLACE 0,0,WEST");
        round.addCommand("MOVEEEE");
        round.addCommand("REPORT");

        HttpEntity<Object> simulationRound = getHttpEntity(round);

        ResponseEntity<Report> resultAsset = template.postForEntity("/robot/simulation", simulationRound, Report.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(resultAsset.getBody(), report);
    }


    @Test
    public void ignoringCommandThatCausesFailTest() {

        Report report = new Report();
        report.addOutput("0,0,SOUTH");

        SimulationRound round = new SimulationRound();
        round.addCommand("PLACE 0,0,SOUTH");
        round.addCommand("MOVE");
        round.addCommand("REPORT");

        HttpEntity<Object> simulationRound = getHttpEntity(round);

        ResponseEntity<Report> resultAsset = template.postForEntity("/robot/simulation", simulationRound, Report.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(resultAsset.getBody(), report);
    }


    @Test
    public void simulationRoundWithoutReportTest() {

        Report report = new Report();

        SimulationRound round = new SimulationRound();
        round.addCommand("PLACE 1,2,EAST");
        round.addCommand("MOVE");
        round.addCommand("MOVE");
        round.addCommand("LEFT");

        HttpEntity<Object> simulationRound = getHttpEntity(round);

        ResponseEntity<Report> resultAsset = template.postForEntity("/robot/simulation", simulationRound, Report.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(resultAsset.getBody(), report);
    }



    private HttpEntity<Object> getHttpEntity(Object body) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    }


}
```

**Notes on solution:**

- All commands will be ignored until a valid PLACE command.
- The robot can be re-PLACEd at any time.
- Any number of REPORT commands are allowed.
- The REST-API request body is a Simulation Round object that contains a list of commands.
- The REST-API response object is a Report object that contains a list of reports, which is the output of the REPORT command if any.
- Many Integration tests are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't examine all the classes.  Here is my (partial) analysis:

### REST API

Your API consists of one call.  This is clearly not what was intended by the question (they did state that they regard the design of the API as important...)

First thing when designing a REST API is to decide what is(are) the entities that are represented by the API, and then decide what are the actions that can be done on these entities.

Although your API is superficially desgined around a "Simulation Round" entity, in essence it is designed to take and do commands.  This is more inline with a design of RPC (remote proc call) API.  It also returns OK status code no matter what's the input.

The entity should be the Robot.  Placing the Robot is analog to creating a new entity.  Moving and rotating the robot is updating its state and reporting is, naturally GETting its state .  So

`POST /robot`       should accept `X,Y,F` as body and return a unique Robot-id
`PUT  /robot/{id}`  should accept move and rotation commands and return either OK  or 404 Not Found or some error indicating the command was ignored (perhaps 409 Conflict)
`GET  /robot/{id}`  should return the state of the Robot (or 404)
`DELETE  /robot/{id}`  will delete the specified Robot (or 404)
All non GET calls should return 400 (bad request) for invalid input.  I mean input that cannot be parsed at all

... and just like that, you designed a service that supports multiple robots...

### ENUM

You should harness the power of arguments to enum to eliminate need for switch statements:

1. CommandType.java
   I would add an instance of `Command` as argument.  This saves the switch statement in the command factory
2. CardinalDirection.java
   I would add the result `CardinalDirection` of right and left rotation as parameters to the enum.  This saves the switch statements in the commands.
   Better still, why not *order* the enum values by right rotation: `NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST` and then you use the enum's `ordinal()` value to determine the result of right (+1) and left (-1) rotations (with wrapping of course)

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your answer and time!
for the REST API part, I thought they want one API to simulate the movement. 
Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation looks like a perfect Gang of 4.

Ask yourself do you really want to work for these people anyway.

I got asked the same question and got AI to build it. Why wouldn't you.

They also rejected it. There is no rhyme or reason.

Asking seasoned coders to do a test like this is stupid IMHO - It's like asking a builder to hammer some nails and screws into a piece of wood.

I always invoice for half a day of work for these tests - they don't always pay.

Read my prompts here.

https://github.com/warrenc5/toyrobot

Comment: There's not very much actual _review_ here - just a little in the first sentence.  The rest just seems like a rant about prospective employers' time-wasting; possibly justified, but absolutely no use for improving the code (as for "why not AI?" - many good reasons, but this isn't the place for that).